# In which Demon Slayer arc the slayer corps mark is explained?

Tags: demon-slayer

In *Demon Slayer* anime until the Entertainment District arc, I believed that only Tanjiro can have marks, but in the Swordsmith Village anime arc, it is shown that both Muichiro and Mitsuri get demon slayer marks. However, in anime, it's not explained about the marks.

So, in which arc the marks will be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the manga, the mark is explained more in detailed in chapters

> [128](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_128) and [129](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_129), which fall during the "Hashira training arc". For the anime adaptation, the Hashira training arc has confirmed to be the next arc (released date TBA)